# Auto-renewable subscription, how to get the user (client) email address and zip code?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

How can I get the user email address and his zip code address when I'm validating an receipt got from an auto-renewable item receipt?

When the user buys my item he has to agree with providing me contact data like email, zip code and so on... but so far I found no way to get the email using the StoreKit API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find informations about a new tool published by Apple in order to download `Opt-In Reports`, containing informations about user subscriptions infos, here : [AppStoreReportingInstructions.pdf](http://www.apple.com/itunesnews/docs/AppStoreReportingInstructions.pdf) See **3.2. Auto-Ingest Tool**